# git History view in Eclipse changed unintentionally, how do I get back to "default"?

Tags: java, git, eclipse, version-control

I have recently started to work with Java and git and followed a [tutorial](https://www.vogella.com/tutorials/EclipseGit/article.html) (I am new to eclipse and java so please don't be too harsh if the question is trivial.).

After I attempted to merge branches yesterday for the first time, I seem to have changed something, so that my history view in Eclipse now looks like this.
[image: Current state of Eclipse History view]

Since then, I started from scratch, created a new repository (test_repository) and would expect the version history of my elaborated script to look something like this (GitKraken).
[image: This is what my version history "should" look like.]
Can someone help me how to revert back to [this history view](https://www.vogella.com/tutorials/EclipseGit/img/exericse_historyview20.png) in Eclipse?

Comment: From the main area only the table header is visible, because you give the revision comment and details almost all the space. Move the separator that is shown directly below the table header (`Id     | Message                   | Author         | ....`) down using the mouse, so there is more space for the main area.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently, the history view was just hidden under the diff view window.. Fixed it.. I am sometimes such a derp..

Comment: Nice. Could you mark your question as closed?